# Huawei switch does not work for EditText and AutoCompleteTextView. Cursor blocks and softkeyborad do not show up

Tags: android, android-edittext, cursor, autocompletetextview, huawei-mobile-services

I have Huawei P9 Lite 7.0 Android and a problem on it.

On the screen I have `EditText` (name), spinner (supplier) and article (`AutoCompleteTextView`).

On `onCreate` method Article field is disabled, and I put cursor in name and type, after that click and select Supplier spinner which enable Article field. 
Then switch cursor from Name to Article field and continue type, it types in Name field,but cursor is switched to Article field.
 At some point it blocks soft keyboard and won't display it and must kill the application.

This happens just on Huawei model, on the other phones it works perfectly. Could somebody know whit is the problem and how to fix it? Thx

Comment: Please provide the code of your Layout and the log cat.

Comment: There is not any error in log, app not crash,just freeze and works slowly. And I can not copy code here because I am under the contract about Confidentiality of information :(

Comment: It's very hard understand what you re doing and reproduce the error.  Try to add some logs to find out when end where the app stucks

Comment: SOLVED! For other people, problem was in background thread. When I removed some function to fill autocomplete adapter from bgd thread, everything works fine.